# HTTPS Requests in Ruby

Tags: ruby, https

Is there a gem or library for HTTPS Requests in Ruby? What is it called and can you provide some example usage?

What I am trying to do is open a page, parse some text from it, and then output it.

Comment: Were you asking about http or https requests? The question title doesn't match the body.

Comment: Since all of the answers are about HTTPS, I changed the question to ask about HTTPS.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## SSL Request with Ruby Standard Library

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
Net::HTTP.get URI('https://encrypted.google.com')
```

`Net::HTTP` in Ruby (>= 2.0.0) performs SSL verification by default if you pass a URI object that has a "https" URL to it. See https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/778bbac8ac2ae50f0987c4888f7158296ee5bbdd/lib/net/http.rb#L481

You may verify this by performing a get request on a [domain](https://expired.badssl.com) with an expired certificate.

```
uri = URI('https://expired.badssl.com/')
Net::HTTP.get(uri)
# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

## SSL Request with Ruby HTTP gems

If you wish to use an alternative, you may use the following gems that also performs SSL verification by default:

1. [Excon](https://github.com/excon/excon)

Excon is a pure Ruby HTTP implementation.

```
require 'excon'
Excon.get 'https://encrypted.google.com'
```

2. [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb)

Curb is a HTTP client that uses libcurl under the hood.

```
require 'curl'
Curl.get 'https://encrypted.google.com'
```

3. [http.rb](https://github.com/httprb/http)

HTTP or http.rb is a pure Ruby HTTP implementation but uses [http_parser.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb) to parse HTTP requests and responses. Since http_parser.rb uses native extensions, it claims to be one of the fastest HTTP client library. But as always, take benchmarks with a grain of salt.

```
require 'http'
HTTP.get 'https://encrypted.google.com'
```

4. [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient)

HTTPClient is another pure Ruby implementation.

```
require 'httpclient'
HTTPClient.get 'https://encrypted.google.com'
```

What's listed here are HTTP libraries and not HTTP wrappers. Wrapper gems like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) and [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) either wrap around a particular HTTP implementation or use adapters to provide a unified HTTP interface. You may check out this [Comparison matrix of Ruby HTTP client features](https://spreadsheets0.google.com/pub?hl=en&hl=en&key=0AiZsKd8d4hSJdHFFbjR5aWNjWjlzWlhiNGxQejdBWWc&output=html). It compares the features of every single HTTP client library out there. But do note that the information **isn't updated since 2012**.

Comment: I think you ment client not http in `http = HTTPClient.new`  it should be `client = HTTPClient.new`

Answer (score 2):

There is an integrated library in the language called `Net::HTTP`

An example usage of it would be:

```
uri = URI('https://example.com/some_path?query=string')
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
puts response.body
```

**UPDATE:**
You need to include that library like this:

```
require 'net/https'
```